# What is the actual response should look like in JSON by this swagger definition?

Tags: swagger

In swagger, if I define the response object like the following, what is the actual response in JSON should look like if another developer follows Swagger responses object definition?

```
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Update success
```

Comment: There is no JSON body defined in the given response.

Comment: Yes, so what's the response should look like? just 200?

Comment: Given that it does not have a JSON body defined, I would think that the HTTP response (with code 200) contains an empty body (not empty JSON `{}`)